# Show and Hide Main Window on Electron

Tags: javascript, electron

Instead of quit the application, I'd like to hide the main window when the system close button is clicked and show the main window when the application is clicked or activate. I'm using the following code to do this on my Electron app:

```
'use strict'

import { app, BrowserWindow } from 'electron'

let mainWindow
const winURL = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
  ? `http://localhost:${require('../../../config').port}`
  : `file://${__dirname}/index.html`

function createWindow () {
  /**
   * Initial window options
   */
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    height: 620,
    width: 350,
    resizable: true,
    fullscreenable: true
  })

  mainWindow.loadURL(winURL)

  mainWindow.on('closed', () => {
    mainWindow.hide()
  })

  // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
  console.log('mainWindow opened')
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
  mainWindow.show()
})
```

But, hiding and showing the window from the `activate` and `closed` event shows the following error and never show the main window when the application is active.

```
Uncaught Exception:
Error: Object has been destroyed
    at BrowserWindow.<anonymous> (/app/src/main/index.js:24:16): mainWindow.on('closed')
```

Not sure what else to do.

Comment: I had this same problem when I was starting. It was hard for me to solve. Let me see if I can find the code.

Comment: I wished it worked like this by default for OSX. Do you want Windows to work the same way?

Comment: I would like to make it work on all platform. Were you able to figure it out? Can you please give me some hint?

Comment: On a somewhat related question, is there something in docs that shows how to check if a window is visible or not?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

My solution is this:

```
import { app, BrowserWindow } from 'electron'

let win = null

function createWindow () {
  win = new BrowserWindow({width: 1024, height: 768})
  win.loadURL('...')
  win.webContents.openDevTools()
  win.on('close', (event) => {
    if (app.quitting) {
      win = null
    } else {
      event.preventDefault()
      win.hide()
    }
  })
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', () => { win.show() })

app.on('before-quit', () => app.quitting = true)
```

In this way on OSX if you close the window, the window simply hide, if you close the app with cmd+Q the app terminate.

Comment: Thats the solution I was looking for. Thanks @Pioz

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, and it will prevent the window from closing, and will just hide it.

You are listening to the `closed` event. But you need to listen to the `close` event. In that event, you can prevent the default action, and just do your hide.

```
mainWindow.on('close', event=>{
    event.preventDefault(); //this prevents it from closing. The `closed` event will not fire now
    mainWindow.hide();
})
```

Once you do this, you won't be able to close your window. So you will want to add a Menu to your app, with an accelerator of `CmdOrCtrl+Q`. Then in there, you can tell the app to quit.

```
const {app, Menu} = require('electron');

Menu.setApplicationMenu(Menu.buildFromTemplate([
    {
      label: "Quit",
      accelerator: "CmdOrCtrl+Q",
      click() {
        app.quit();
      }
    }
]));
```

And this will allow you to Cmd+Q to quit your app.

Comment: Yeah, it does work. But it causes a new issue. I can't close the application complete at all. It just always hide but if even press `command + q`, the app never close at all. Any idea?

Comment: @MdMazedulIslamKhan I updated my answer. Try that and let me know if it works.

Comment: Unfortunately, this still doesn't close the application.

Comment: I would need to see more of your code in order to continue troubleshooting. This works. If it isn't working on your code, I would need to see your entire code base. Any chance you have a repo?

Comment: FYI I have a very similar behavior using the above - it appears that app.quit() gets intercepted by the above logic. Something like the solution from @Pioz above.